# Add a first day column to table with expression

Tags: mysql, date, alter-table, dateadd

I am using Below code to add a first day of the month column to the table with an expression to update automatically. But it's throwing a syntax error. someone pls do help.

```
ALTER TABLE `abc`.`t1` 
ADD COLUMN `First_Day` DATE NULL DEFAULT select DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(report_date),
        INTERVAL 1 DAY),
    INTERVAL - 1 MONTH) AFTER `Totals`;
```

Comment: First day as in sun,mon,tues or first day as in 01?

Answer (score 0):

mysql won't allow to use expressions for setting default values.

you can create trigger for this purpose.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON `product` 
FOR EACH ROW SET
    NEW.myCol= DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(new.report_date),
        INTERVAL 1 DAY),
    INTERVAL - 1 MONTH);
END$$
delimiter;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would question why you would wish to store this but if you must a generated column might do.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id int, report_date date);

ALTER TABLE t
ADD COLUMN `First_Day` DATE as 
(date_add(date_add(last_day(date(report_date)),interval 1 day),interval -1 month));

insert into t (id,report_date) values
(1,'2018-01-08'),(2,'2018-02-09');

select * from t;

 +------+-------------+------------+
| id   | report_date | First_Day  |
+------+-------------+------------+
|    1 | 2018-01-08  | 2018-01-01 |
|    2 | 2018-02-09  | 2018-02-01 |
+------+-------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I you choose to go this way or via a trigger you will have to write a one off update to populate this column for existing data.